# Web site on Azure App Service having certificate problem on Chrome

Tags: azure, ssl, azure-web-app-service

I have a couple of web apps running on a single Azure App Service. I've uploaded a wildcard certificate to the app service and bound it to the relevant hostnames. When I open the app the first time in Chrome the green lock is displayed in the address bar. If I close the tab and open a new tab and try to open the web app I get the following message under the address bar.

[image: Address error message]

When I checked the security tab in Chrome Developer Tools I can see this message.

[image: Security message]

The first time I connect to the site the security tab in Chrome Developer Tools looks like this:

[image]

I'm using the same certificate on a website hosted on SiteGround and I'm not having problems with the certificate there. This looks to be an issue on Azure.

I am using IIS to redirect to https in the web.config rather than using the "HTTPS Only" setting on the Azure portal. Even if I change this setting I'm still having the same issue with the certificate.

This only seems to happen on Chrome. Firefox and Edge are not having a problem.

Are there any settings I need to change in order to fix this?

**Updated**
I've also checked the site using [SSL Labs SSL Server Test tool](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest). Our own certificate is being recognized as trusted but there is another certificate further down in the results that is being recognized as not trusted.

[image: Certificate 2 Results]

Comment: Google did recently put their HTTPS only warning system into effect. If any site is coming across as HTTP, it will be flagged. Can you please verify that the site is loading as HTTPS in Chrome? Beyond this, it would be great to dig deeper into your site. Can you please indirectly share your site name with us by following these steps: https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Reporting-your-site-name-without-posting-it-publicly

Comment: As far as I can tell all the resources are being served using HTTPS. I've added a screenshot of the Security tab in Developer Tools the first time that I connect to the site. The partial sub ID is 88b7...767f and the partial site name is tru...testv2

Comment: I've added a copy of this question to [the MSDN forums](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/68f156d4-7381-4c4d-b11f-a0bfa5645058/web-site-on-azure-app-service-having-certificate-problem-on-chrome?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview) too